# Make Gmail not turn a URL into a link

Tags: gmail

I'd like to send an email that contains a URL like `yahoo.com`, but I don't want Gmail to turn it into a link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put an [LRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) into the URL, like this in Python 3:

```
yahoo\u200e.com
```

This caused Gmail to not render it as a link.

Comment: In general, it does not look as a good idea, because if you copy and paste, the browser (at least Firefox) tries to open `http://www.yahoo%e2%80%8e.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen others override this by writing something like:

> yahooDOTcom

where the reader can figure it out.